# Show/Hide navigation item depending on value from localstorage angular ui-router

Tags: angularjs, navigation, angular-ui-router, local-storage, angular-material

I have a module like

```
  function config(msNavigationServiceProvider)
    {
        // Navigation
        msNavigationServiceProvider.saveItem('apps', {
            title : 'APPS',
            group : true,
            weight: 1
        });

        msNavigationServiceProvider.saveItem('apps.dashboards', {
            title : 'Dashboards',
            icon  : 'icon-tile-four',
            weight: 1
        });
    }
```

Where [`msNavigationServiceProvider`](http://pastie.org/10841119) is provider which is part of core package.
 The problem is that I want to hide `Apps` Item on Navigation bar accoding to the value in localstorage but I cannot access `$localStorage` in config() provider error. I have research about it found that it is not possible.

So what should I do to hide item from Navigation . I dont want touch the core packages but I also cannot use localstorage in my code.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you have access to the `run` method? Maybe you can try removing the items from there

Comment: Actually I am new to this how can I access this method? It would be very helpful if you can tell me that

Answer (score 4):

You can use the hidden attribute in the `msNavigationService`

```
hidden: function ()
        {
            return boolean; // must be a boolean value
        }
```

Example:

```
// Apps.Dashboards
msNavigationService.saveItem('apps.dashboards', {
    title : 'Dashboards',
    icon  : 'icon-tile-four',
    class : 'navigation-dashboards',
    hidden: function ()
    {
        return AuthService.isAdmin; // must be a boolean value
    },
    weight: 1
});
```

Comment: I cannot get to inject AuthService into msNavigationServiceProvider... I'm running the provider in the config block. Thanks